# Stack images over a centred svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm playing with svg and flexbox at this moment and I would like to stack an image on top of a centred svg.

The image should be in the center of the svg and I would also like to accomplish that the image scales along proportionally with the svg.

Is it possible to accomplish this with flexbox or should I consider something else?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <img src="https://www.stadiumgoods.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/base/1000x600/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/6/365054_02_1.png" alt="sneaker" class="sneaker" />
      <svg id="circle-bg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle fill="#F8F5F5" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #EBEBED;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.spotlight {
  width: 50vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
}

.sneaker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}

#circle-bg {
  height: 75vh;
}
```

JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/hvgom8o3/

Expected Result:

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `.spotlight` a flexbox:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/hvgom8o3/1/)

```css
body {
  background-color: #EBEBED;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.spotlight {
  width: 50vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sneaker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
}

#circle-bg {
  height: 75vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <img src="https://www.stadiumgoods.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/base/1000x600/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/6/365054_02_1.png" alt="sneaker" class="sneaker" />
      <svg id="circle-bg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle fill="#F8F5F5" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Gerard, but my problem is now only partially solved.

The problem that I still have is that the shoe is not centered in the middle of the circle and when I resize my window it is grouped with the svg.

Comment: For perfect vertical alignment you need to adjust the image. There is a lot of space around the shoe which makes it look like the shoe itself is positioned too low.

Comment: It is both horizontal and vertical alignment I would like to achieve, but even when replacing the image in your example I cannot achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

With the inspiration of Gerard and other posts on Stackoverflow I found a smooth solution.

Applying auto margins to the absolute positioned image in combination with setting top,right,bottom and left to zero, did the trick.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="spotlight">
      <img src="https://www.stadiumgoods.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/base/1000x600/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/6/365054_02_1.png" alt="sneaker" class="sneaker" />
      <svg id="circle-bg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle fill="#F8F5F5" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #EBEBED;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.spotlight {
  width: 50vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sneaker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/146t817h/1/